# What is meant by "relaxed standards" for P2SH redeem scripts in Bitcoin Core 0.10.0?

Tags: bitcoin-core, transactions, p2sh, non-standard-transaction

From the [Bitcoin Core 0.10.0 release notes](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/0.10/doc/release-notes.md#standard-script-rules-relaxed-for-p2sh-addresses):

> **Standard script rules relaxed for P2SH addresses**
>
> The IsStandard() rules have been almost completely removed for P2SH
>   redemption scripts, allowing applications to make use of any valid
>   script type, such as "n-of-m OR y", hash-locked oracle addresses, etc.
>   While the Bitcoin protocol has always supported these types of script,
>   actually using them on mainnet has been previously inconvenient as
>   standard Bitcoin Core nodes wouldn't relay them to miners, nor would
>   most miners include them in blocks they mined.

So essentially the core software will now relay more intricate P2SH Txns which would previously be deemed *non-standards transactions*.

What are the specific changes which have been made (ie relaxed standards)? Does it only apply to P2SH Txns? Finally, `"n-of-m OR y"` and `hash-locked oracle addresses` are mentioned as examples: what does this refer to exactly?

Comment: `IsStandard` doesn't seem to have changed at all; perhaps the developers meant to refer to `IsStandardTx`? In any case, I can't find the changed code.

Comment: @nickodell Yep, that was my understanding. I do still need clarification of `n-of-m OR y` and the Oracle addresses

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What are the specific changes which have been made (ie relaxed standards)?

Gavin Andresen made [this pull request](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/4365) proposing the change, as well as [this rationale document](https://gist.github.com/gavinandresen/88be40c141bc67acb247) describing why he supported the change.

> Does it only apply to P2SH Txns?

It applies only to P2SH [redeem scripts](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-guide#term-redeem-script), which is the script that is run to see if you have the data required to spend an output sent to a P2SH address.

> Finally, "n-of-m OR y" and hash-locked oracle addresses are mentioned as examples: what does this refer to exactly?

- `n-of-m OR y` refers to a script that checks for multiple signatures from a set of keys OR a single signature from another key.  For example, if Alice owns a business and Bob and Charlie are her employees, she can allow Bob and Charlie to work together to spend her bitcoins (2-of-2) or Alice ("y") can spend her bitcoins on her own.
- `hash-locked oracle` means, generally, that you can create a transaction that can only be spent when the hash of some data is provided.  For example, [this PDF](http://lightning.network/lightning-network.pdf) (page 24) describes a hash-locked contract with three parties: Alice, Bob, and Charlie.

  - Alice wants to pay 1.00 BTC to Charlie through Bob.
  - Charlie randomly generates a large number *r* and then hashes (HASH160) that number to produce *h*.  The value *r* is the oracle and the value *h* is the hash lock.
  - Charlie gives hash *h* to Alice.
  - (Transaction 1) Alice gets Bob's pubkey and pays him 1.01 BTC in an output with a script like: `<Bob's pubkey> CHECKSIGVERIFY HASH160 <hash h> EQUAL`
  - (Transaction 2) Bob can't spend that output without the number *r* that generated hash *h*, but he knows Charlie has the number *r* so Bob gets Charlie's address and pays him 1.00 BTC with a script like: `<Charlie's pubkey> CHECKSIGVERIFY HASH160 <hash h> EQUAL`
  - (Transaction 3) Charlie spends the output from transaction 2 by creating the signature script: `<number r> <Charlie's signature>`  This means *r* is revealed on the block chain.
  - (Transaction 4) Bob sees *r* on the block chain and uses it at some point to spend the output from transaction 1: `<number r> <Bob's signature>`

  The example above seems overly contrived, but the PDF linked above uses it as part of a micropayment channel that allows settling transactions off the block chain in a distributed and low-trust manner, possibly allowing Bitcoin to scale much better than it does without such a system.

Comment: Wow that's fascinating. If possible can you clarify a working example of an Oracle script that could work without miner interception?

Comment: @WizardOfOzzie I can't think of any examples of hash-locked oracles that are simpler than solving the same problem without hash-locked oracles---unless the spender is a miner and doesn't have to worry about miner interception.  Sorry.

Comment: @WizardOfOzzie I just read [this PDF](http://lightning.network/lightning-network.pdf) (starting page 24) which describes a hash-locked **contract**, which is what I guess Peter Todd was thinking of when he wrote about hash-locked oracles in the release notes.  I'll update my answer to describe the process in a few minutes.